# How can I decompile an swf file and get the original scripts?

Tags: flash, decompiling

When I am decompiling an swf file, and get variables named `_loc1_`, `_loc2 _`, `loc3_` ...

How can I decompile an swf file and get the original scripts?

Comment: check it out https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/issues/407-loc1-instead-of-register1

Answer (score 3):

> How to **decompile swf** file and get **original scripts**?

You can't!! A swf is a **compiled** application, not a text document. When it becomes `.swf` format its no longer the **original scripts** (as saved in `.as` file) but it is now machine code (see **Actionscript Virtual Machine** in online articles or wiki's).

For original var names, some decompilers work better (at least on un-obfuscated code) so you gotta try them all.
To a machine, a variabe doesn't need an understandable name like `hero`, `baddie` or `weapon`... instead it can be `loc1`, `loc2` and `loc3`. Decompilers have to guess from your SWF data what the original AS3 might look like (sometimes it's a bad guess, which gives non-working code).

Only use decompilers for code-recovery of lost sources (if decompiled code is 70% usable, you can "remember" your original logic and fix the rest, or even rename vars to original names).

Answer (score -2):

Many of flash applications have been protected by some types of code-obfuscators.(renamers or Ugifyers or Minifiers) flash scripts are normaly accesible for  original codes even comments. But you cant reverse an obfuscated code to its original with any decompiler.